# Instantiate an object in razor view Asp.net Mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a razor view strongly bound to a viewmodel:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyViewModel
```

I want to make an instance of another viewmodel in the same view page and use it:

```
@test = new MyNamespace.AnotherViewModel();

@test.SomeAction();
```

I receive compilation error:

```
The name 'test' does not exist in the current context
```

I am very new to asp.net mvc and was not able to make it work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can denote multiple lines of code by wrapping it within a `@{ code }` for multi-line statements:

```
@{ 
    var test = new MyNamespace.AnotherViewModel();
    test.SomeAction();
}
```